# Python equivalent of R "split"-function

Tags: python, r, grouping

In R, you could split a vector according to the factors of another vector:

```
> a <- 1:10
  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> b <- rep(1:2,5)
  [1] 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2

> split(a,b)

   $`1`
   [1] 1 3 5 7 9
   $`2`
   [1]  2  4  6  8 10
```

Thus, grouping a list (in terms of python) according to the values of another list (according to the order of the factors).

Is there anything handy in python like that, except from the `itertools.groupby` approach?

Comment: Can you be little more clear on your input and output ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your example, it looks like each element in b contains the 1-indexed list in which the node will be stored. Python lacks the automatic numeric variables that R seems to have, so we'll return a tuple of lists. If you can do zero-indexed lists, and you only need two lists (i.e., for your R use case, 1 and 2 are the only values, in python they'll be 0 and 1)

```
>>> a = range(1, 11)
>>> b = [0,1] * 5

>>> split(a, b)
([1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
```

Then you can use `itertools.compress`:

```
def split(x, f):
    return list(itertools.compress(x, f)), list(itertools.compress(x, (not i for i in f)))
```

If you need more general input (multiple numbers), something like the following will return an n-tuple:

```
def split(x, f):
    count = max(f) + 1
    return tuple( list(itertools.compress(x, (el == i for el in f))) for i in xrange(count) )  

>>> split([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [0,1,1,0,2,3,4,0,1,2])
([1, 4, 8], [2, 3, 9], [5, 10], [6], [7])
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: warning, this a `groupby` solution, which is not what OP asked for, but it may be of use to someone looking for a less specific way to split the R way in Python.

---

Here's one way with `itertools`.

```
import itertools
# make your sample data
a = range(1,11)
b = zip(*zip(range(len(a)), itertools.cycle((1,2))))[1]

{k: zip(*g)[1] for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(zip(b,a)), lambda x: x[0])}
# {1: (1, 3, 5, 7, 9), 2: (2, 4, 6, 8, 10)}
```

This gives you a dictionary, which is analogous to the named list that you get from R's `split`.

Comment: Nice solution, but I asked for a non-iterools.groupby version; see question

Answer (score 1):

As a long time R user I was wondering how to do the same thing. It's a very handy function for tabulating vectors. This is what I came up with:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b = [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]

from collections import defaultdict
def split(x, f):
    res = defaultdict(list)
    for v, k in zip(x, f):
        res[k].append(v)
    return res

>>> split(a, b)
defaultdict(list, {1: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9], 2: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b = [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]

split_1 = [a[k] for k in (i for i,j in enumerate(b) if j == 1)]
split_2 = [a[k] for k in (i for i,j in enumerate(b) if j == 2)]
```

results in:

```
In [22]: split_1
Out[22]: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

In [24]: split_2
Out[24]: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

To make this generalise you can simply iterate over the unique elements in b:

```
splits = {}
for index in set(b):
   splits[index] =  [a[k] for k in (i for i,j in enumerate(b) if j == index)]
```